# parse html tags from string and make an array in javaScript, vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am trying to make an array from string. the string contains HTML *tags* like **P**, **span**, **a**,**img**. some are nested like **span** tag inside **p**, **img** tag inside **a** etc. i would not replace any **tags** or **styles**. I am trying to parse all the tags and make an array.

Example code looks like this in **textData** variable

```
var line_array =[];
var textData : `
     <img src="imgurl" alt="" /> 
     <p>some text</p>
     <p style="cssStyle">some text</p>
     <span style="cssStyle"> some text </span>
     <p style="cssStyle">some text<span style="cssStyle"> span text </span></p>
     <a href=""><span style="style">text</span><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt=""/>  </a>
`
activate: function (){
      let sourceText = document.getElementById('sourceText').innerHTML;
      line_array = sourceText;
}
```

I am trying to make an array look like this... from **textData**

```
line_array =[
'<img src="imgurl" alt="" />', 
'<p>some text</p>', 
'<p style="cssStyle">some text</p>',
'<span style="cssStyle"> some text </span>',
'<p style="cssStyle">some text<span style="cssStyle"> span text </span</p>',
'<a href=""><span style="style">text</span><img src="imgurl" alt=""/></a>'
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard or impossible to do with regexp alone (depending on the complexity of HTML that you want/need to allow). You can use [split-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split-html).

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/split-html@1.1.0/index.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const textData = `
               <img src="imgurl" alt="" /> 
               <p>some text</p>
               <p style="cssStyle">some text</p>
               <span style="cssStyle"> some text </span>
               <p style="cssStyle">some text<span style="cssStyle"> span text 
               </span></p>
                <a href=""><span style="style">text</span><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt=""/>  </a>
        `
        const line_array = splitHtml(textData, 'img, a, p').filter(String);
        console.log(line_array);
    </script>
```

Comment: Not at all, if it helps, mark that the answer is accepted